# Give an example of a solvable group of prime exponent which is not nilpotent.

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups, nilpotent-groups

I came across two examples on Wikipedia -"McClain's Example" and "Tarski Group" ; but of them looked quite complicated .Are there any other somewhat simpler examples which satisfy the above requirements?

Comment: I am doubtful whether you will find simple (meaning easy!) examples. The proofs that the Burnside groups $B(n,p)$ are infinite for sufficiently large primes $p$ (something like $p > 665$) are already horrendously long and technical.